# mysql query how to show single record for orders

Tags: php

I am having tables as

**table 1**

```
**userregistration**        
id          int pk
firstname   nvarchar    
lastname    nvarchar    
image   nvarchar
```

**table 2**

```
**customerorder**       
id          int pk
vid         int fk
cid         int fk
datetime    datetime    
totalamount double  
tip         double  
coupon      double  
isspecial   int fk
orderstatus int
```

**table 3**

```
**ordermenu**       
id          int pk
orderid     int fk
itemname    nvarchar    
quantity    int 
price   double
```

when I run following query:

```
SELECT userregistration.firstname,userregistration.lastname,userregistration.image,customerorder.datetime,customerorder.totalamount,customerorder.tip,customerorder.coupon,customerorder.isspecial,customerorder.orderstatus,ordermenu.itemname,ordermenu.quantity 
FROM userregistration
JOIN customerorder ON userregistration.id=customerorder.cid 
JOIN ordermenu ON customerorder.id=ordermenu.orderid
WHERE userregistration.id=151
```

And it shows

```
firstname   lastname    image   datetime    totalamount     tip     coupon  isspecial   orderstatus     itemname    quantity    

Jay     Rathore     /images/53ef0...    2014-08-16 00:00:00     100.00  10.00   20.00   1   1   Drinks  2

Jay     Rathore     /images/53ef0...    2014-08-16 00:00:00     100.00  10.00   20.00   1   1   Chips   2
```

I do not want to show repetation of *firstname  lastname    image   datetime    totalamount*..

So how to show that?

Answer (score 0):

```
You may use Group By condition to the query to avoid the repetation.
Example:
SELECT userregistration.firstname,userregistration.lastname,userregistration.image,customerorder.datetime,customerorder.totalamount,customerorder.tip,customerorder.coupon,customerorder.isspecial,customerorder.orderstatus,ordermenu.itemname,ordermenu.quantity FROM userregistration JOIN customerorder ON userregistration.id=customerorder.cid JOIN ordermenu ON customerorder.id=ordermenu.orderid WHERE userregistration.id=151 Group By userregistration.firstname,userregistration.lastname
```